# SyntaxError: when passing prop types into test cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, mocha.js

- I am trying to write the test case for my jsx file...
- i took the sample test case from another jsx file...
- i am facing syntax error....when passing proptypes....
- I think because of this its breaking my test case...
- can you guys tell me how to fix it..
- providing my code below...

clear code below **https://gist.github.com/js08/d590e78e8923e68b191a**

---

SyntaxError: C:/codebase/sports/test/sports-tests.js: Unexpected token (20:73)
  18 |
  19 |     it('should render correctly', () => {
**> 20 |         shallowRenderer.render();**
     |                                                                          ^
  21 |         /*let renderedElement = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
  22 |

```
test case
import {expect} from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import sportsPageDefault from '../src/sports-Page-Default';
import initializeJsDom from './test-utils/dom.js';
import {getGridLayoutClasses} from 'sports-css-grids';
//import _difference from 'lodash/array/difference';


describe('shallow renderer tests for sports-Page-Default ', function() {
    let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    console.log("shallowRenderer" + JSON.stringify(shallowRenderer));


    it('should render correctly', () => {
        shallowRenderer.render(<sportsPageDefault headerClass='8887' layout= {id: 100, text: 'hello world'} sidebar= {id: 100, text: 'hello world'} title="Demo" />);
        let renderedElement = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
        console.log(renderedElement);

       /* let actualTitleEl = renderedElement.props.children[0].props.children[0];
        let expectedTitleEl = <h1 className="transactionalPageHeader-appName font-serif">Demo</h1>;
        expect(actualTitleEl).to.deep.equal(expectedTitleEl);*/
    });



});

actual code

import './css/sports-bottom-layout.css';
import './css/sports-Page.css';
import './css/sports-leftCornerLayout.css';

import React from 'react';
import PageHeader from './components/page-header/page-header';
import MainContent from './components/main-content';
import sports-bottom-layout from './components/sports-bottom-layout/sports-bottom-layout';
import {getPanelLayoutState} from './util/PageLayout';
import {getGridLayoutClasses} from 'sports-css-grids/lib/js/gridLayout';
import PagePureRenderMixin from './util/PagePureRenderMixin';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setHeaderPanelState, setRightPanelState} from './redux/layout/layout-actions';

console.log("inside");
let customMixin = PagePureRenderMixin({
    state: {
        mainPanelGridClassList: function(classArray) {
            return classArray.length;
            console.log("classArray.length" + classArray.length);
        }
    }
});

let PT = React.PropTypes;

let sportsPageDefault = React.createClass({


    propTypes: {
        headerClass: React.PropTypes.string,
        layout: PT.object.isRequired,
        sports-leftCornerLayout: PT.oneOfType([
            PT.func,
            PT.object
        ]),
        title: PT.string.isRequired
    },


    //cpomponent m,ount code

});

function sportsShallow(itemA, itemB) {
    for (let i in itemA) {
        if (itemA[i] !== itemB[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

export default connect(state => ({
    layout: state.Page.layout
}))(sportsPageDefault);

**but another file it works fine, for example**
 propTypes: {
        footer: React.PropTypes.bool,
        onAppExit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },
        let component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<sports title="Demo" onAppExit={onAppExit}/>);
```

Comment: `sports-leftCornerLayout` is not a valid property name, could you try it without the hyphen?

Comment: @MartinWedvich but even after removing hyphen its not working :(